# как избавиться от доменного имени localhost в начале адресной строки

Tags: openserver, wamp

недавно я перешел с OS на wamp, скажем так для разнообразия, проблема заключается в том ,что на OS не надо вводить в адресной строке сначала localhost, а сразу доменное имя сайта. А в wamp надо, как же избавиться

Comment: а можно почитать, где написано, что надо избавиться?

Comment: при каждом заходе на сайт нужно вводить сначала localhost/mysite/. это на wamp сервере, 
но на  OpenServer  я вводил только  домен сайта, без localhost

Comment: Не понял, а зачем избавляться? В чем суть вопроса? Тебе лень набирать `localhost`?

Comment: все проекты расположены в директории www/

Comment: Это особенность wamp значит??  без localhost никак?

Comment: Да.............

Comment: дело не в том, что мне не в мочь,  на OpenServer у меня было без этого, все проекты были в директории domains/, а на  wamp www/, а  тут надо писать localhost/mysite

Comment: ааа.... скорее всего  htaccess на это влияет, там надо наколдовать

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ut1jOOMH61o

Comment: Прописать в c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts любой адрес какой хотите  на 127.0.0.1

Comment: Поставьте laragon и забудьте об этих устаревших пакетах под Windows